# How to use datetime.strptime with 12:00 format?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm having trouble converting a string to using `datetime.strptime`

```
import time
import pandas as pd

tm = ('12:00')
datetime.strptime(tm, '%I, %M')

ValueError: time data '12:00' does not match format '%I, %M'
```

Is there another format I should be using?

Comment: `datetime.strptime(tm, '%I:%M')`?

Comment: The error message is telling you everything that's needed. You're using ',' instead of ':'.

Answer (score 2):

Since your input looks like `12:00`, it is in the form `<hour>:<minute>`, so you need to use the format specification `%I:%M`.

NB: `%I` will only ever be between `01` and `12` – if the first number in your timestamp can ever be greater than 12, you should use `%H` instead.